# How do you get clojure yesql output the SQL it would execute?

Tags: clojure

I want to debug my yesql query. So I'm trying to get SQL it would execute.
Can anyone give me an example of how to make yesql output the SQL it would execute?

It's not good example... I mistake parameter name 'tel' for 'phone'.

users.sql

```
-- name: insert-user
-- insert a user data to users table. 
insert into
users  ( name,  age,  tel,  address,  remark)
values (:name, :age, :tel, :address, :remark);
```

query.clj

```
(ns example.sql.query
  (:require [yesql.core :as yesql]
            [example.sql.datasource :as ds]))

(yesql/defqueries {:connection {:datasource ds/datasource}})
(yesql/insert-user {:name "joe" :age 22 :phone nil :address "xxxxxx" :remark ""})
```

Comment: yesql uses sql files you write and doesn't generate sql (other than parameter substitution). what's your exact problem? can you give an example where you've set it up and want to see the output?

Comment: In Development, I sometimes catch sql syntax errors by passing a wrong values to parameters. To see sql it would execute help me to find a problem quickly.
```

```

Comment: if you're only interesting in stopping bad data going into the call, you could build functions around your queries that have pre conditions to check values to parameters. better than going all the way to the d/b before erroring

Answer (score 3):

In general (as mentioned in the comments), yesql shouldn't be doing a whole lot of SQL generation; the concept is that it passes through the queries you've written.

With that said, if you still want to try to see the raw query yesql is passing to JDBC, here's a hack to get pretty close:

```
(require 'yesql.generate)
(require 'yesql.statement-parser)

(defn debug-yesql-query [queryfn args]
  ;; queryfn should be a query function generated by yesql
  ;; args should be a map of query args, just as if you were
  ;;   calling the query function
  (let [sql-source (-> queryfn meta :yesql.generate/source)]
    (yesql.generate/rewrite-query-for-jdbc
     (yesql.statement-parser/tokenize sql-source)
     args))
```

Tested with yesql version 0.5.2.

Comment: thank you! I got it and that's a greate code for me.